# rails 3.2 strange behavior with jquery-ujs

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i'm trying to disable a input while i'm submiting it in a remote form.

My coffee code is like this:

```
todoSubmitForm = $('form.todo-form')
todoSubmitForm.on 'ajax:before', ->
    input = $(this).find('input#todo')
    return false if not input.val() and not input.val().match /^\s+$/
    input.attr 'disabled', 'disabled'

todoSubmitForm.on 'ajax:complete', ->
    $(this).find('input#todo').removeAttr 'disabled'
    turbolinksRefresh()
```

But, the input that I disable was not submited that way.
I don't know if it's a bug or if I'm doing something wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fields from disabled input elements are not submitted as part of the form.

You can set it to `readonly`:

```
input.attr 'readonly', 'readonly'
```

Comment: it almost works, I just add a blur() in the input too, so the user cannot press return a million times. Thanks ;)